# Python printing only one file

Tags: python, function, class

Can someone explain me, why my function out() prints only one file? how can i fix, bcs it should print a lot of files recursively from 2019 DIR

```
class log():

    def __init__(self, search):
        self.search = search

    def get_files(self):
        path = '/var/log/HOSTS/dhcpd-s/2019'
        for root, directories, filenames in os.walk(path):
            for directory in directories:
                #do whatever u want with absolute dirs path
                dir_path = os.path.join(root, directory)

            for filename in filenames:
                #do whatever u want with absolute file path
                file_path = os.path.join(root, filename)
                if os.path.getsize(file_path) == 0:
                    pass
                else:
                    self.file_path = file_path

    def out(self):
        print(self.file_path)


if __name__=='__main__':
   p = log(search = sys.argv[1])
   p.get_files()
   p.out()
```

Comment: You're overwriting the same variable over and over. If you look at what file is actually the output, then it should be the "last one" in the directory.

Comment: if i print self.file_path in get_files function its fine, but i want get output in out() function ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running in a loop

`self.file_path = file_path`

In each iteration it assigns new file path and after exiting the loop it holds the value of last iteration.

You can declare `self.file_path`  as a `list`

```
def __init__(self, search):
        self.search = search
        self.file_path = []
```

And append `file_path` into the list

```
self.file_path.append(file_path)
```

Now you can print all paths

```
def out(self):
    for path  in self.file_path:
        print(path)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
class log():

    def __init__(self, search):
        self.search = search

    def get_files(self):
        files = []
        path = '/var/log/HOSTS/dhcpd-s/2019'
        for root, directories, filenames in os.walk(path):
            for directory in directories:
                #do whatever u want with absolute dirs path
                dir_path = os.path.join(root, directory)

            for filename in filenames:
                #do whatever u want with absolute file path
                file_path = os.path.join(root, filename)
                if os.path.getsize(file_path) == 0:
                    pass
                else:
                    files.append(file_path)

         self.files_path = files
    def out(self):
        print(self.file_path)


if __name__=='__main__':
   p = log(search = sys.argv[1])
   p.get_files()
   p.out()
```

Answer (score 0):

Below (collect data into a list)

```
import os 
import sys

class log():

    def __init__(self, search):
        self.search = search
        self.file_path = []

    def get_files(self):
        path = '/var/log/HOSTS/dhcpd-s/2019'
        for root, directories, filenames in os.walk(path):
            for directory in directories:
                #do whatever u want with absolute dirs path
                dir_path = os.path.join(root, directory)

            for filename in filenames:
                #do whatever u want with absolute file path
                file_path = os.path.join(root, filename)
                if os.path.getsize(file_path) == 0:
                    pass
                else:
                    self.file_path.append(file_path)

    def out(self):
        print(self.file_path)


if __name__=='__main__':
   p = log(search = sys.argv[1])
   p.get_files()
   p.out()
```